# wmctrl, xdotool: Move all windows by just 1px

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

My notebook suffers from image persistence and I want to create a program that moves every second the whole screen just 1 pixel to left and in the next second to the right (one pixel offset every second shouldn't be noticable for the user, right?). I've already tried to create programs with wmctrl and xdotools, but it's nearly impossible to move a fullscreen window (with both of them).
With wmctrl it's not possible to minimize a certain window. (I've already asked that question here: [wmctrl: moving a fullscreen window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755831/wmctrl-moving-a-fullscreen-window)

And with `xdotool` it's possible to move a window, but that's not one pixel, it's way more.

```
#!/bin/bash

windowIds=$(xdotools search -class "")

for windowId in $windowIds; do
    name=$(xdotool getwindowname $windowId)
    geo=$(xdotool getwindowgeometry $windowId)
    if [[ $name == *"Firefox"* ]]; then
        foo=$(xdotool windowmove --relative $windowId -1 -1)
    fi
done
```

If you have any idea how I can solve this issue, I would be very thankful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: not to discourage you but if you can't see a difference, how will it help against image persistence?